# findViewById on Custom Title Bar within Tab Activity

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I have a custom title bar set on my TabActivity. The custom title bar contains a TextView and an ImageView in it. The tabHost has multiple tabs.

What I want to do is to access the ImageView resource in the tabs.

I am accessing the TextView from custom title bar in the main Tab activity (that extends TabActivity) and it is working fine. Following is the code which is working fine in main activity:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mycustomtitle);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewTitleId);
```

Now I want to access the ImageView in my tabs (which are added in tabHost). If I set following code in tab:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

It gives following error:

```
You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

And if i directly set following in the tab code:

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mycustomtitle);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageTitleId);
```

The image remains null.

mycustomtitle.xml has following two elements:

```
<TextView 
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="0.80"
     android:id="@+id/viewTitleId"
     android:textColor="@color/titleBarTextColor"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:text="@string/viewText"
     android:textSize="18px"
     android:paddingLeft="45px"
     />

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_save" 
    android:id="@+id/imageTitleId"
    >
</ImageView>
```

Please give me some idea how can I access the Custom title's ImageView in the tabs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the `TextView` and `ImageView` by declaring them `public static` in the `TabActivity`. Then, in the `Sub-Activity` you obviously access the public static TextView and ImageView like,

```
Main_Tab_Activity.textView.setText("my_text_view");
```

Comment: This is really bad advice. Please stop creating memory leaks for SO users.

Comment: if you don't explicitly null the public static fields they will forever hold the reference to the views, even when the TabActivity instance is destroyed already. and by keeping references to the views you actually leak the whole activity.

Comment: @ct_rob how about adding an alternative solution in this case. Just giving reason is not enough.

Comment: To whom who have knowledge but no time :- 
I am able to see only three answer one from Venky other from Lalit one from JaiSoni..Now in this case 
I have only choice to view them,take them , up them....
If there be any other answer I will consider them too.

Comment: @lalit i'm still searching for an answer myself, i just answered ericlee's questions why the answer given may result in a memory leak. you see a lot of answers on SO that just advise people to use public static references and that is almost always a very bad solution.

Comment: @ct_rob I suggest to store the instance of View in Application class, might e that should be a better way.

Comment: yes, that is slighlty better, since you will probably overwrite this for every screen and thus you will only have one view in memory at the time. A public static variable used in this way still violates a lot OO principles. In my case I found an easy solution. When adding a custom title layout it's contents will also be found by findViewById in the activity. I'm not using a TabActivity though, so I don't know if this applies here as well. cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you put Custom Title bar only in Main TabActivity that Title bar will appears in all of your Sub-TabActivity.

For Example if you gave Custom title Bar in Main TabActivity :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.header_layout);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewTitleId);
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageTitleId);
```

there is no need to give in all you Sub-tab Activity.

In all sub-Tab Activity you just set `setContentView(R.layout.sub_layout);`

Comment: Yes @Venky we can access both textview and imageview in the main tabactivity. But I want to access ImageView in my sub-tab activities. I want different behavior of ImageView on each sub-tab.

Comment: @rizzz86 Why you need to use that Image in sub Activity? By default it will appear in all Sub Activity Right?

Comment: Yes it is appearing on all sub activities. But I need different behavior on each sub-tab when I click on the ImageView. For example when click on ImageView with 1st opening tab it will store value in table1 and if click on ImageView with 2nd opening tab it will store value in table2 etc

Comment: @rizzz86 Come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat chat room..we will discuss

Comment: Thanks for your support @Venky. I got the answer from Lalit Poptani

Answer (score 1):

use

```
getParent().getWindow().findViewById(id)
```

insted id `findViewById(id);`
for access any view of parent.